# HashSet is Adding Duplicate ChannelSftp.LsEntry

Tags: java, hashset, jsch

I am trying to download files via sftp using the jsch library. I am successfully doing that, but I only want to download the file if its not already downloaded. I am gathering a list of entries, and trying to implement a hashset to check and see if they are already downloaded. The problem is, it is adding duplicates to the hashset and redownloading all of the files. Below is the code I have written (well, the important parts).

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls("*.gz");

for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
    if (set.add(entry)) {
        sftpChannel.get(entry.getFilename(), fileDestination); 
    }
}
```

This is all in a method. So, when I call the method again, It should only download the files that I didn't download previously. However, it is not doing that. Any suggestions? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: It all depends on the definition of 'equals' for the result value of 'getFilename()'

Comment: 1) Check how ChannelSftp.LsEntry.hashCode() and equals() methods are implemented. Maybe this class isn't suitable as a hash structure key. 2) Check the scope of the set variable. Does it really remember previous calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `entry` add `entry.getFilename()` to the `set`:

```
if (set.add(entry.getFilename())) {
    sftpChannel.get(entry.getFilename(), fileDestination); 
}
```

What I have assumed here is that `getFilename` returns a `String` and your application permits such a `set` to be defined.

The reason this works (if the assumptions are correct) is because `equals` is well defined on `String` and this will not let two same names (identical sequence of characters) end up in the same `set`.

However if you can not modify `set` you should override `hashCode` and `equals` on `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` reflecting what you think makes two `LsEntry` objects *equal*.

Comment: I found this to be the simplest solution. I just changed the set to be defined as a set of Strings. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Please override the hashCode() and equals() methods for the duplicates issue on HashSet